# Android WebView reuse in an activity

Tags: android, webview, garbage-collection

I want to reuse the WebView several times in an Activity.

When I call WebView.loadData() many times, the usage of memory is increased.

And I cannot see any GC until I get chromium OOM.

( The HTML code I pass into the `loadData()` is loading images. like this, img src=blabla.. )

I have searched many suggestions to clear the WebView, but they do not help my App.

Only way my App does GC, is when I finish the WebView Activity.

Is there any way to clear or destroy WebView without finish Activity?

Below, is my full source code.

```
public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final String tag = "CCTEST_VIEW";
private ListView lvList;
private FrameLayout list_header;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private ArrayList<String> contents;
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
    list_header = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

    lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int pos = position - lvList.getHeaderViewsCount();
            launchWebView(contents.get(pos));
        }
    });

    lvList.setAdapter(adapter);


    SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    String data = prefs.getString("data", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
    contents = new Gson().fromJson(data, type);

    for (int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++) {
        arrayList.add("a." + i);
    }

}

private void launchWebView(String body) {
    genWebView();
    webView.loadData(body, "text/html", "UTF-8");

}


private void clearWebView() {
    if (list_header.getChildCount() == 0) return;


    webView.stopLoading();
    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.pauseTimers();
    webView.removeAllViews();
    webView.setWebChromeClient();
    webView.destroy();
    webView = null;

    list_header.removeAllViews();

}

private void genWebView() {
    clearWebView();
    if (webView == null) {

        webView = new WebView(this);

        list_header.addView(webView);
    }
    else {
        webView.onResume();
    }
}






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: self (half) answer - I have struggled with this problem for a month. only way to avoid to get oom is to use the option setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); but when I use the option, then I get a side effect, "view too large to fit into drawing cache"